# How To Deploy MVC 6 Application On IIS without publish

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How To Deploy  MVC 6 Application RC1-Update1 on IIS without publish so i can use attach process to debug it

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this on your local development machine or on a remote server?

You could run the non-published site with Kestrel by just running `dnx web` and have IIS as the front end using ARR to route the requests from IIS to Kestrel (http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing)

To debug you just attach to the dnx process.